# Call method after asynchronous request obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

In my app I init a new object, where there is method which calls `NSURLConnection`'s `sendAsynchronousRequest` method. After the request, I would like to call a method in the caller UIViewController. I tried to use a static method but I then I can't control `IBOutlet`s. How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
// First test    
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.result = responseBody;
        PhotoViewController *photo = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];
        [photo finishedPost:self]; // Doesnt work
    }
}];

// Second test
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.result = responseBody;
        [PhotoViewController finishedPost:self]; // Doesnt work
    }
}];
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SuH3yGPS

Comment: have you tried using breakpoints in `completion` block? The `photo` object is new reference (because you are allocating it in the block), if you want to update any existing object of `PhotoViewController ` , you have to retrieve it or keep it in the class. As @Glorfindel answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to 'remember' which `UIViewController` calls the object. This can be done for instance with a property.

in .h

`@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;`

in your .m file

`@synthesize viewController;`

Before calling the method, set the property with

```
anObject.viewController = self;
```

Then, you'll be able to call

```
[viewController finishedPost:self];
```

inside the completion handler of the `sendAsynchronousRequest:` method.